# How to enable Kite for PyCharm scratches?

Tags: macos, pycharm, kite

While it works fine for "normal" files, it's not even showing up in the status bar of PyCharm for scratch files. How can I enable this?

Comment: What do you mean by *scratch* files ?

Comment: [Scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/scratches.html) are simply files available in all projects for quick drafts residing in `~/Library/Preferences/<product><version>`, so in essence I want to enable Kite for this directory specifically.

Comment: Maybe try `File->Settings->Project:project_name->Project Structure` and select `Add Content Root` ?

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. Kite ignores this entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scratch files are currently ignored by the Kite PyCharm/IntelliJ plugin.
Recent enhancements of the Kite engine now allow to support this kind of file. It will be implemented in the plugin soon.